# Scaling background image height at different viewport widths without media queries?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, background-image, viewport

I'm working on a project where I have a hero image as a `background-image` for my html `header`tag.

Directly below that I have a flex container with two items in that space themselves throughout the viewport window and resize according to the viewport size. This looks fine when the browser window is at a large viewport size, however, when I start scaling the window down, there begins to show a bit of whitespace between the hero image and the flex container. I would like that flex container to *always* stay directly at the bottom of the hero image.

I realize that this is probably because the hero image has a fixed height on it and is not flexible because it is always going to be trying to render the height at 700px regardless of the viewport size.

I also know that you can resize this based on breakpoints in your CSS, but I just wanted to see if there was another way to do it.

I have attached screenshots so you can have an accurate read of what it is that I am asking

Here is my viewport window at a large size:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTlkw.jpg

Here is my viewport window at a slightly smaller size: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KXpK.jpg

For further clarification:

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type = "text/css" href="css/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/build/main.css">
<title>Summer Breeze</title>
</head>
<body>
<header class = "hero">
</header>
<div class = "container">
  <div id = "stay">
  <div id = "staySquare"></div>
  </div>
  <div id = "gazebo">
  <div id = "gazeboPic"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="js/build/app.min.js" type="javascript"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my SCSS:

```
/*-----------------------------------------------
*   Base
-----------------------------------------------*/
$light-brown : #ddcebb;

body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
/*-----------------------------------------------
*   Hero
-----------------------------------------------*/
.hero {
  background-image: url("../../img/house_front.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size:100%;
  height: 700px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  height:260px;
}

#stay {
  background-color: $light-brown;
  font-size: 100px;
  padding:30px;
  width: 45%;

  #staySquare {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 2px solid black;
  }
}

#gazebo{
  background-color: mistyrose;
  width: 55%;

  #gazeboPic {
    background-image: url("../../img/walkway-to-Beach.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: White space issue has been solved with `background-size: cover;` or alternatively `background-size: auto 100%`. The issue I am running into with this is when I resize the viewport window, the right side of the hero image is getting cropped off as I am making it smaller while the flex container is moving with the viewport window. Is there any way to keep this centered as I'm resizing?

Here is a screenshot : https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSWpo.jpg

Comment: Change `background-size:100%;` to `background-size:cover;` or `background-size: auto 100%;`

Comment: This is definitely a step in the right direction as it solved my main problem, so thank you for that! However the image is no longer centered in the viewport window when I resize it. The right side of the image keeps getting cropped off when I make the viewport smaller. I can post another screenshot if you need me to explain further...

Comment: You control positioning with `background-position`, like `background-position: center center;`, or `background-position: center top;`, or `background-position: left top;` etc ... more to read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background-position

Comment: That'll do! Thanks so much!